# Perl get hash keys value count in single hash itself

Tags: perl, hash

I have written a script which processes data from `$data` variable and get the count of values of each key.

The script works fine but I am producing 2 hashes called `%data_hash`, `%count_hash`. One for storing the data and another to get the count of those key values.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $data = "KEY1,VAL1
KEY2,VAL1
KEY1,VAL2
KEY1,VAL3
KEY1,VAL4
KEY2,VAL2
KEY2,VAL3
KEY2,VAL4
KEY1,VAL5
";

my (%data_hash, %count_hash);
foreach my $each_data (split /\n/, $data){
    my ($key, $val) = (split /,/, $each_data);
    push( @{$data_hash{$key}}, $val );
}

print Dumper(\%data_hash);

foreach my $key (sort keys %data_hash) {
    $count_hash{$key} = scalar @{$data_hash{$key}};
}

print Dumper(\%count_hash);
```

Can I have a single hash instead of 2 and get the count by retaining the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $data = "KEY1,VAL1
KEY2,VAL1
KEY1,VAL2
KEY1,VAL3
KEY1,VAL4
KEY2,VAL2
KEY2,VAL3
KEY2,VAL4
KEY1,VAL5
";

my (%data_hash, %count_hash);
foreach my $each_data (split /\n/, $data){
    my ($key, $val) = (split /,/, $each_data);
    push( @{$data_hash{$key}{vals}}, $val );
    $data_hash{$key}{num_vals}++;
}

print Dumper(\%data_hash);
```